# creating a list of files in bash failed

Tags: bash

I have a folder with the following file content:

```
ls bams-lab/*.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam
bams-lab/OZBenth2_.fastp.fq.gz.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam  
...
bams-lab/OZBenth7_.fastp.fq.gz.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam
```

I tried to create a list of files with the below bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: sh merge_sam_pbs.sh /path/to/*.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam 
output=$(dirname $1)
samlist=$(for sam in $1; do echo "I=$sam "; done)
cat << EOF  |cat #qsub
#!/bin/bash -l
#PBS -N merge
#PBS -l walltime=150:00:00
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -l mem=70G
#PBS -l ncpus=2
#PBS -M m.lorenc@qut.edu.au

cd \$PBS_O_WORKDIR

conda activate picard
echo $samlist

picard -Xmx10g  MergeSamFiles \
      $samlist \
      O=${output}/merged.sorted.dedup.bam

EOF
```

but it only picks up one file

```
> sh merge_sam_pbs.sh bams-lab/*.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam 
#!/bin/bash -l
#PBS -N merge
#PBS -l walltime=150:00:00
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -l mem=70G
#PBS -l ncpus=2
#PBS -M m.lorenc@qut.edu.au

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

conda activate picard
echo I=bams-lab/OZBenth2_.fastp.fq.gz.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam 

picard -Xmx10g  MergeSamFiles       I=bams-lab/OZBenth2_.fastp.fq.gz.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam        O=bams-lab/merged.sorted.dedup.bam
```

What did I miss?

Comment: try with "$samlist" ( double quotes )

Comment: @kamaraj that won't work at all; it will give you one word containing space-separated elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It picks up one file only, because `$1` **is just one file**.

The `*` is interpreted when you call your script, so your call

```
sh merge_sam_pbs.sh bams-lab/*.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam
```

is issued as

```
sh merge_sam_pbs.sh "bams-lab/1.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam" "bams-lab/2.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam" "bams-lab/3.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam"
```

with `$1` then being `"bams-lab/1.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam"`.

---

You want to use `"$@"` in the `for`loop:

```
samlist=$(for sam in "$@"; do echo "I=$sam "; done)
```

or better replace the for loop with `printf`:

```
samlist=$(printf 'I=%s\n' "$@")
```

or even better for your use case, add quotes and a space instead of newline:

```
samlist=$(printf 'I="%s" ' "$@")
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the script as being a bash shell script so I'm going to assume that's what you're intending to use. (Don't run it with `sh script`, though; use `bash script` instead. They can be different shells.)

You can replace the `samlist` string with an array of file elements

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> # usage: sh merge_sam_pbs.sh /path/to/*.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam 
> output=$(dirname $1)
> samlist=$(for sam in $1; do echo "I=$sam "; done)
> ```

Becomes

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: bash merge_sam_pbs.sh /path/to/*.name-sorted.fixmate.sorted.dedup.sam

# Create output directory based on first filename passed to the script
output="${1%/*}"

# For all the filenames passed to the script, prefix with 'I=', and add to array
samlist=()
for sam in "$@"
do
    samlist+=("I=$sam")
done
```

And now you can use the array you've created. So instead of this

> ```
> picard -Xmx10g  MergeSamFiles \
>       $samlist \
>       O=${output}/merged.sorted.dedup.bam
> ```

You can use this

```
picard -Xmx10g  MergeSamFiles "${samlist[@]}" O="$output/merged.sorted.dedup.bam"
```

Notice that I've quoted all of the variables when I've used them. This stops the shell trying to process the individual space-separated items. Furthermore, if the `"{samlist[@]}"` contains to no elements, it simply disappears. Take a look at [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/100397) for more details.